# sqlite incremental vacuum removing only one free page

Tags: sqlite, vacuum, autovacuum

I have changed value of auto_vacuum PRAGMA of my sqlite database to INCREMENTAL. When I run `PRAGMA incremental_vacuum;` through 'DB Browser for SQlite' application it frees all the pages in the `free_list`.
But when I am running same statement using any SQLite library in C# (e.g. `Microsoft.Data.SQLite`), it frees only one page from the `free_list`

I verified this by getting the number in current `free_list` by running `PRAGMA freelist_count` before and after running `PRAGMA incremental_vacuum` statement.

Also I tried passing different parameters to `incremental_vacuum` pragma e.g. `PRAGMA incremental_vacuum(100)` but it would still free only one page.

Please let me if what is it that I am doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you run a `VACUUM` after changing the `auto_vacuum` setting?

Comment: @Shawn Yes i did. I can see in the PRAGMAs of database that auto_vacuum value is INCREMENTAL. without calling VACUUM it will not allow the value to change. And also the `incremental_vacuum` runs fine through `DB Browser for SQLite` application

Comment: In my case I get only one page removed in SQLiteStudio

Answer (score 1):

This happens if one ignores the result from `sqlite3_step()`. If it returns `SQLITE_ROW`, the code cannot act as if it had returned `SQLITE_DONE`. One has to keep calling `sqlite3_step()` until the query is done: pragma or not, a query is a query and it isn't done until it's, well, `SQLITE_DONE` :). It happens to remove one page at a time:

```
bool do_incremental_vacuum(sqlite3 *db) {
   sqlite3_stmt *stmt = nullptr;
   auto rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "pragma freelist_count;", -1, &stmt);
   if (rc != SQLITE_OK) return false;
   rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
   if (rc != SQLITE_DONE && rc != SQLITE_ROW) return false;
   auto freelist_count = sqlite3_column_int64(stmt, 0);
   rc = sqlite3_errcode(db);
   if (rc != SQLITE_OK && rc != SQLITE_DONE && rc != SQLITE_ROW) return false;
   std::cout << "There are " << freelist_count << " pages in the free list." << std::endl;

   rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, "pragma incremental_vacuum;", -1, &stmt, nullptr);
   uint64_t pages = 0;
   if (rc != SQLITE_OK) return false;
   do {
      rc = sqlite3_step(stmt);
      if (rc == SQLITE_ROW) ++ pages;
   } while (rc == SQLITE_ROW);
   if (rc != SQLITE_DONE) return false;

   std::cout << "Freed " << pages << " pages" << std::endl;
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. My C# version based on your suggestion (sorry for bad code formatting): 

`var command = new SQLiteCommand("pragma incremental_vacuum", _db);  using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) { while (reader.Read()) { ++result; } Logger.WriteLine($"{result} pages removed by the incremental vacuum command"); }`