# PRAGMA incremental_vacuum(1000) will only remove one page, why?

Tags: sqlite

I have a `test.db` an `sqlite3` database. `auto_vacuum=incremental` however, when I call `PRAGMA incremental_vacuum(1000)` after deleting a huge amount of the database, the `incremental_vacuum` only remove the size of one page `-4096B or 4K` and I can't figure out why it does that.

Is there a limit cap on how many pages to be removed?

Is there a `compile_option` that I don't know off that has to be changed?

All ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention how you access the SQLite database. One of possible reasons may be that your code uses (directly or indirectly via some wrapper library) the [sqlite3_step](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) API, which vacuums 1 page per step.

If this is the case, then you need to either loop until sqlite3_step() returns SQLITE_DONE (instead of SQLITE_ROW), or switch to using the [sqlite3_exec](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) wrapper instead.

Please see the [possibly similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53746807/sqlite-incremental-vacuum-removing-only-one-free-page).

Answer (score -1):

You should try using the [VACUUM](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) command, this will rebuild the database omitting deleted data.

Using `PRAGMA incremental_vacuum(1000)` will only release pages that are in the free list (you can use `PRAGMA freelist_count` to obtain the number of pages in the free list).